# Error- Class UpdateFutureCasesToNewStatus must implement the method: System.Iterable<Case> Database.Batchable<Case>.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

Trying to get batchable class setup.

Getting Error:

Class UpdateFutureCasesToNewStatus must implement the method: System.Iterable Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)

```
global class UpdateFutureCasesToNewStatus implements Database.Batchable<Case> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
        String query = ([Select Id, Status, Future_Date_for_Completion__c
                         from Case Where Status = 'Pending - Future Date for Completion' AND Future_Date_for_Completion__c = TODAY]);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> FutureCasesList) {
        // process each batch of records default size is 200
        For (Case CaseList: FutureCasesList){
            CaseList.Status = 'New';
            CaseList.Future_Date_for_Completion__c = Null;
            CaseList.Comments = 'Future Dated Case, being reassigned to the working queue.' ;
            CaseList.First_Team_Line__c = false;
        }  
        try {               
            Update FutureCasesList ;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error: '+ e);
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // execute any post-processing operations like sending email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'me@myemail.com'};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setReplyTo('support@id.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Apex error message');
        mail.setSubject('Error from Org : ' + UserInfo.getOrganizationName());
        mail.setPlainTextBody(e.getMessage());
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems:

1. Main error: Implements should be on `SObject` and not `Case`.

   ```
   implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
   ```

   - <del>I remember `implements Database.Batchable<Case>` used to work years ago, could be new compiler is more strict now</del>
2. Another problem is with assignment of a list to String in the start method, it should be as:

   ```
    return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, Status, Future_Date_for_Completion__c
        from Case Where Status = 'Pending - Future Date for Completion' 
        AND Future_Date_for_Completion__c = TODAY]);
   ```

---

Note: Its advised to not use global access modifier unless you really have to.

Comment: It still does work, but you have to cast the Database.QueryLocator to an `Iterable<Case>` instead. It's a kind of silly thing, but that's how the compiler works. `public Iterable<Case> start(...)` ... `return (Iterable<Case>)Database.getQueryLocator([...]);`

Comment: Wondering if you'd be able to shed light on why i'm not able to cover the Execute method? I have everything else covered in test just not that method for some reason.